# Block sending requests twice react-redux (hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have some hook for fetching countries array from api :

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const useCountries = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch()

 const { countries } = useSelector(data => data)

 useEffect(() => {
   if (!countries.length) {
     dispatch(getCountries())
   }
 }, [countries])

  return {
    countries
  }
}
```

I have some components which aren't on the same level of DOM , and aren't related to each other

```
const FirstComponent = () => {
  const {countries} = useCountries()

  // some using of countries array
}

const SecondComponent = () => {
  const {countries} = useCountries()

  // some using of countries array
}
```

When page loading 2 of these components, are executed, and 2 actions are dispatched. Because countries aren't selected yet in first and in the second component it calls API request. My question is, how can I prevent sending the second request if some request was sent. Make some rule for sending request only once, if try to send the second one, then block it. Or what is the correct solution or approach in my case?

Also, I've tried a case like this :

```
  const {
    external: { response, isInitial }
  } = useSelector(data => data)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!response && isInitial) {
      dispatch(setIsInitial(false))

      fetch()
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
           setResponse(data)
        })
    }
  }, [dispatch, response, isInitial])
```

Here is my reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  response: null,
  isInitial: true
}

export default function external(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_RESPONSE:
      return {
        ...state,
        response: action.payload.data
      }
    case types.SET_INITIAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isInitial: action.payload.data
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

But it sends 2 requests

Comment: You can have a `fetching` flag. 

Also, you can write the logic such that an api call will only be made when state does not have the value or you need to flush the state and fetching is not true.

Comment: Could you attach some code solving example, pls for my case!

Comment: posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `useCountries` as below:

```
const useCountries = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch()

 const countries  = useSelector(state => state.countries);
 const isFetching = useSelector(state => state.isFetching);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (!countries.length && !isFetching) {
     dispatch(getCountries()) 
   }
 }, [countries, isFetching])

  return {
    countries
  }
}
```

You would need to flip the `isFetching` flag in your `getCountries` function and flip it again when the `api` has resolved.

------------------EDIT after additional information-----------------------

You would need to chain your `dispatch` calls. This is to ensure that flag is set before you make the api call.

To achieve that you can make `dispatch` thenable in the following way.

`dispatch` returns either of two:

> For sync action (like dispatch ({type: 'ACTION'}) it will return
>   action object ({type: 'ACTION'} in my example)
>
> For thunk actions (action creators which return functions) it returns
>   the same result returned from action creator.

This is the first case.

```
const syncAction = (arg1, arg2) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Promise.resolve(arg1 + arg2);
    }
}
```

This would be the second case.

```
const asyncAction = (arg1, arg2) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return fetch(/* some request */)
      .then(response => dispatch({ type: "RESPONSE_RECEIVED", payload: response }));
  };
};
```

Now armed with two above, you can do the following:

```
dispatch(syncAction(...args)).then(() => {
    dispatch(asyncAction())
});
```

In your case `syncAction - isInitial` and `asyncAction - getCountries()`.

Comment: You mean dispatch some action which set isFetching to true? It will not work, because, these hooks will be called almost simultaneously, could you show how you set isFetching in reducer?

Comment: `dispatch` is always syncronous in nature. 

You can have a `dispatch` which specifically sets the flag. 

You can `dispatch` just before you make an api call. 

This way only one `dispatch` will be called for api. The other will just dry run through useEffect because it won't enter the `if` block. 

You can add the reducer into your post. I'll edit it.

Comment: You need to chain the `dispatch` calls, I'll add example in my answer.

Comment: export function setIsInitial() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { external } = getState()

    if (external.isInitial) {
      return Promise.resolve(
        dispatch({
          type: types.SET_IS_INITIAL_SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            data: false
          }
        })
      )
    }

    return Promise.reject()
  }
}

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich Can you please accept my answer then :).

Answer (score 0):

Addind `dispatch` to useEffect dependencies array whould solve the issue.

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch()

 const { countries } = useSelector(data => data)

useEffect(() => {
   if (!countries.length) {
     dispatch(getCountries())
   }
 }, [countries, dispatch])
```